# Strange behaviour of ternary plot in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ternary

I want to include a ternary plot in a shiny app. I'm use package ggtern.

When I run the following code:

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,1,5), y=c(45,29,10), z=c(10,45,94),
                ss=c(58,75,109))

ggtern(data=dd,
         aes(x=x,y=y,z=z)) +
  geom_mask() +
  geom_point() +
  Larrowlab("var1") + Tarrowlab("var2") + Rarrowlab("var3") +
  theme_showarrows() +
  theme(tern.axis.arrow.show=T)#,
          #tern.axis.text.show=F)
```

I get:

[image]

Inside a shiny app:

```
library(ggtern)
library(shiny)
## data ####
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,1,5), y=c(45,29,10), z=c(10,45,94),
                ss=c(58,75,109))
################
runApp(

  ## UI ####
  list(ui = (basicPage(
    headerPanel("ternary test"),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("gg", click = "plot_click")
    )
  )),

  ## server ####
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$gg <- renderPlot({

      ggtern(data=dd,
             aes(x=x,y=y,z=z)) +
      geom_mask() +
      geom_point() +
      Larrowlab("var1") + Tarrowlab("var2") + Rarrowlab("var3") +
      theme_showarrows() +
      theme(tern.axis.arrow.show=T)#,
              #tern.axis.text.show=F)
    })

  }
  ))
```

I get this:

[image: grafico]

Why the differences?
Is this a bug? Anyway around it?

Thanks,
António

Comment: Try doing `a<-ggtern`... followed by `print(a)` in your `renderPlot`, seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Indeed it does! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `print(ggtern_plot)`, as suggested in the comments above does not translate plot clicks properly and does not scale the plot.

`ggtern` does not work with shiny well because `ggtern` overloads `plot.ggplot` but shiny does not use the overloaded function. I managed to fix the plot this way:

```
custom_print.ggplot <- function(x) {
    ggtern:::ggint$set_last_plot(x) # this is line needed by ggtern
    # based on ggplot2:::custom_print.ggplot
    grid::grid.newpage()

    data <- ggplot_build(x)
    gtable <- ggplot_gtable(data)
    grid::grid.draw(gtable)
    invisible(data)
    structure(list(
        build = data,
        gtable = gtable
    ), class = "ggplot_build_gtable")
}
assignInNamespace("custom_print.ggplot", custom_print.ggplot, "shiny")
```